# What's the most compact representation of a sequence?

Tags: data-structures, clojure

I am storing a mapping and I have `seq`s of integers as keys. The hashmap is quite large (100,000 keys) so I want the most compact possible storage method to conserve RAM.

There are a few options out there, including Clojure `LazySeq`s, vectors, `java.util.Arrays` or even strings. I don't need laziness, persistence or interned-ness of the above, just to use them as opaque keys.

Is there's known minimal smallest representation of this kind of data?

**edit** because the question wasn't clear I want to use a hashmap because of the features it provides. I don't want another abstract data type. I am interested in minimising the size of the keys.

Comment: Are these arbitrary sequences of integers, or are there any constraints such as min/max length or values that could be used to compress them?

Comment: They are, I would say, impossible to compress if you're thinking of things like RLE. They're about 5 digits long and obviously each sequence is unique.

Answer (score 2):

If memory optimisation is important, you may want to use a Java native array of int (or long). But then you will need to define a wrapper class in order to have the right `equals` and `hashcode` contracts fulfilled since Java native arrays are objects but just inherit `equals` and `hashCode` from `Objects`. 
I haven't done any measure, but - depending on the number of ints in your key sequence - and knowing the data structure behind immutable Clojure vector, this may have a significant impact.

To do that native array keys, you can use utility functions in `java.lang.Arrays`, and define a simple wrapper in Java:

```
public final class IntKey {
    private final int[] data;

    public IntKey(int[] data) {
        if (data == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof IntKey)) {
            return false;
        }
        return Arrays.equals(data, ((IntKey)other).data);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(data);
    }
}
```

Or do it in Clojure with `deftype`:

```
(deftype IntKey [^ints data]
  java.lang.Object
  (equals [this other] 
    (java.util.Arrays/equals data (.data other)))
  (hashCode [this] 
    (java.util.Arrays/hashCode data)))
```

Then test native arrays **are not** good keys:

```
(def k1 (int-array [1 2 3]))
(def k2 (int-array [4 5 6]))
(def k3 (int-array [1 2 3])) ;; same sequence as k1

(def h (hash-map ik1 "hello" ik2 "good" ik3 "bye"))

user> (map h [ik1 ik2 ik3])
user> ("hello" "good" "bye")  ;; argh ik1 and ik3 should yield the same value
```

Wrap the int arrays in `IntKey`and redefined the map:

```
(def ik1 (IntKey. k1))
(def ik2 (IntKey. k2))
(def ik3 (IntKey. k3))

(def h (hash-map ik1 "hello"  ik2 "good" ik3 "bye"))

user> (map h [ik1 ik2 ik3])
("bye" "good" "bye") ;; ok
user> (count h)
2
```

Note: you may want to "cache" hashcode values in the wrapper class to compute it only once per sequence.

Comment: This is probably most efficient in terms of memory, but you must be extremely careful not to mutate the contents of the arrays once they're added as keys or else lookups will be broken. In general, mutable keys in hashmaps are asking for trouble.

Comment: Yes, I did not mention it, but certainly in this design, keys should be immutable.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just found `vector-of`, which looks very similar. http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vector-of

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on operations you'll need to do on this data. Most common solution for this will be [[set, value], ...], though it'll not be much better ram-wise than hashmap. It's probably time to move to external K/V?

Comment: Are you suggesting store the whole structure as a vector? If so, why? It doesn't give any of the functionality of a hashmap (lookup, unique keys).

Comment: it's called tuplelist. anyway - you just want to find most efficient storage for keys? in this case vector is the best candidate.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, this really depends on the operations you would need to perform on the data.

For example, you could use [bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) if you dont mind a certain degree of false positive (but no false negative), Or, if the keys are static, you could use a [minimal perfect hash function](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/tools/org/h2/dev/hash/MinimalPerfectHash.java), that you could use to access, say, an array or a file.

**Update**

bloom filters are indeed used to represent sets and not maps. However, I found an interesting paper generalizing [bloom filters into maps](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/miles/phd-projects/talbot.pdf). Didnt yet find any implementation of it though.

Comment: I'm using the hashmap because I want all of its features! Specifically, storing arbitrary (multiple) values, retrieval, updating etc etc. I'm not sure what you mean by static keys- surely all hashtable keys have to be immutable?

Comment: And aren't bloom filters used to represent sets rather than mappings?

Comment: I think 'static' in this context means keys are not being added to or removed from the map over the life of the application. If you can be guaranteed a hash function with no duplicates for your given keyset, you can store the hash directly in the map.

Comment: Ah right! No, I that doesn't apply but it's an interesting idea.